# If-then-else statement use

Tags: java, if-statement

Method: “run”

- Create endless loop
- If MerkleManager.sMerkleRoot is not null then...
- If the above merkle root equals the initial user-entered merkle root.Then print out “You win: “ followed by the merkle root and exit the app.
- Else if they’re not equal, then tell the user he lost – and exit the app.

My code:

```
public void run() {

    while (true) {
    }
    if MerkleManager.sMerkleRoot = null;
    {

    } else {

    } 
    System.exit(0);
}
```

How do I set `MerkleManager.sMerkleRoot` not null and use if-then-else statement?

Answer (score 0):

In your check you are assigning the value of MerkleManager.sMerkleRoot with "=" assignment operand.

Instead you should be checking "==" or "!=" operand to compare the object references.

```
public void run() {

    while (true) {
    }
    if MerkleManager.sMerkleRoot != null
    {

    } else {

    } 
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will never leave the while loop the way it's written.

Change to this,

```
public void run() {

    while (true) {
      if MerkleManager.sMerkleRoot != null{
         // do stuff
      }else {
        // do something else
      } 
    System.exit(0); // if you leave this statement, your code will exit on the first exec
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are saying that you want it to exit the JVM whether the condition is met or not which would render the while loop useless as the first iteration would guarantee a termination for either case (and the way you have it currently will get you stuck in the loop and never execute the following line anyways) so you can remove that completely.

Second, you need parentheses around the boolean statement in an if clause in java.

What you want to do for your method might look a little more like this

```
public void run() {
    if (MerkleManager.sMerkleRoot != null && MerkleManager.sMerkleRoot == inputRoot) {
        System.out.println("You won");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("You lose");
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
```